# How to return meaningful results from type PSMethod

Tags: rest, powershell

I'm doing a simple API call to a government database. I am interested in the address field. Although it looks like a hash, I can't get the values.

Here is the API call:

```
$searchTerm = "01446754"
$url = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search?q=$searchTerm"
$apiKey = "myregisteredapikey"

$authVal = "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($apikey))

$header = @{
    "Authorization"=$authVal
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' 
$results = $response.items
$results
```

In this example, searching by company number, I get the following dataset returned:

```
links                  : @{self=/company/01446754}
description_identifier : {incorporated-on}
kind                   : searchresults#company
company_status         : active
address                : @{premises=Lakeside Works Rocester; postal_code=ST14 5JP; locality=Staffordshire; address_line_1=Uttoxeter}
date_of_creation       : 1979-09-05
address_snippet        : Lakeside Works Rocester, Uttoxeter, Staffordshire, ST14 5JP
description            : 01446754 - Incorporated on  5 September 1979
company_type           : ltd
company_number         : 01446754
title                  : JCB LIMITED
```

All good, until I do `$results.Address` which returns:

```
OverloadDefinitions                                                                                        
-------------------                                                                                        
System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Address(int )
```

I am not sure what this is telling me. Intellisense adds a bracket to the end; (which, I think) suggests it is an object, so I tried:

```
PS C:\> $results.Address()
Cannot find an overload for "Address" and the argument count: "0".
At line:1 char:1
+ $results.Address()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Clearly, I don't know what I am doing here, but I tried to use one of the fields returned in the 'address' hash:

```
PS C:\> $results.Address('postal_code')
Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "postal_code", for "Address" to type "System.Int32": "Cannot convert value "postal_code" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input 
string was not in a correct format.""
At line:1 char:1
+ $results.Address('postal_code')
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

So it seems to want an integer, so I tried:

```
PS C:\> $results.Address(1)
Exception calling "Address" with "1" argument(s): "Operation could destabilize the runtime."
At line:1 char:1
+ $results.Address(1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VerificationException
```

Ok, lets look at what type 'address' is:

```
PS C:\> $results.Address.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     False    PSMethod                                 System.Management.Automation.PSMethodInfo
```

So how do I get the values out of the object of type PSMethod?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've got it. Although I am not sure if it is the best way. I don't understand why the apparent hashtable is of type PSMethod. But then I'm not a developer :-(.

Doing `$results.Address.Invoke(0).address` returns:

```
PS C:\> $results.Address.Invoke(0).address

address_line_1 locality      postal_code premises               
-------------- --------      ----------- --------               
Uttoxeter      Staffordshire ST14 5JP    Lakeside Works Rocester
```

So putting it all together, I end up with:

```
$searchTerm = "01446754"
$url = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search?q=$searchTerm"
$apiKey = "myregisteredapikey"


$authVal = "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($apikey))

$header = @{
    "Authorization"=$authVal
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' 
$results = $response.items

$oData = @()

foreach($company in $results)
{
    $oAddress = $company.address

    $oData += [pscustomobject]@{
        CompanyName = $company.title
        CompanyType = $company.company_type
        CompanyNumber = $company.company_number
        Date = $company.date_of_creation
        Premises = $oAddress.premises
        Town = $oAddress.address_line_1
        Locality = $oAddress.locality
        PostCode = $oAddress.postal_code

    }
}

$oData
```

Although in the pscustomobject, I had to remove `.invoke(0).` and create the object `$oAddress` in the for-loop.

### Update

I've gone a little bit further. The problem with this particular API is that there is a limit of 100 records per page (or request) so when there are more than 100 records, the code has to iterate over the pages.

My initial example used 'JCB' (yes, the yellow diggers!!) as the search term. Although the API says there are 448 results, it appears there actually aren't so I was getting odd results. I searched for "amazon" instead, returning  372 records, and all seems fine.

I could have requested 1 result per page that would have made my life simpler but this would have meant 448 individual requests, slowing down my code and as I found out, I soon received an error "too many requests" from the server, so there must be a ceiling somewhere. Apparently, the developers of this particular API have put some thought into this item per page limit, as can be read about [here](http://forum.aws.chdev.org/t/why-is-filing-history-limited-to-100-items-per-page/131/3). Personally, I don't agree and the server resource hogging they are worried about must be no more than milliseconds. It would have made life much easier if one could pull all records in one request, or up the limit to a much more reasonable count, but this is a government department, and they think differently to everyone else (IMHO).

Anyway, as a learning exercise, it's been useful. I have put (undocumented) [code on GitHub](https://github.com/arcotek-ltd/PSCompaniesHouse) for anyone interested. If you have the time / inclination, please feel free to improve. I should really put this code into a module, but that's for another day.

Any improvements welcome.

TIA.